# Get rid of the group by variable in a case expression Redshift

Tags: mysql, group-by, amazon-redshift, case-when

I am migrating code from MySQL syntax to Amazon Redshift and I  have an issue with the group by .
So, a field in the code:

```
,CASE WHEN condition NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) THEN 0 ELSE measure END as field
```

On Redshift, code requires group by condition . If I do not add this field in the GROUP BY clause, the code will not run. On the other hand, on the MySQL code , the group by is not used, and also not compulsory for the code to run. The thing is that this group by causes the code to return 38K rows, duplicates, versus 24K that it should normally return.
I also added this group by in the MySQL code and it returned 38K rows, same as RS, which proves that the group by causes the duplicates that I wish to discard.

So Redshift syntax obliges to group by a variable used in the CASE WHEN statement, while MySQL syntax does not. And this causes my Redshift code to return multiple rows.
How can I put this field on RedShift and discard the group by , or the duplicates somehow?

Comment: My guess here is that your MySQL code is doing an invalid `GROUP BY` which selects non aggregate columns.  It doesn't run on Redshift.  You added the above `CASE` statement to the `GROUP BY` clause to make it run, but now you don't get the expected result set?  Is that correct?  In any case, please add the full query and some sample data to your question.

Comment: Hello. I did NOT add the case statement in the GROUP BY clause. Instead I only added the condition in the group by clause
group by condition. BTW condition is yet another table column . 

A code example is: 

Select t1.field1, t1.field2, .... t2.field1, 
,CASE WHEN t2.field2 NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15) THEN 0 ELSE t2.measure END as field10
from table1 t1
left join table2 as t2 on t1.id=t2.id
group by t2.field2